# How to resolve 'TypeError: waveshow() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given' error?

Tags: python, deep-learning, librosa

I tried the below code in pycharm. Then it gave the error, 'AttributeError: module 'librosa.display' has no attribute 'waveplot'. Did you mean: 'waveshow'?'. Then I used, 'waveshow', instead of the waveplot method. But now I am getting the error, '**TypeError: waveshow() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**'. Though I searched for the error I did not find a way to resolve it. Does anyone have a proper solution for it?

```
e= "happy"
plt.figure(figsize=(14,4))
librosa.display.waveplot(data, sampling_rate)
create_spectrogram(data, sampling_rate, e)
Audio(path)
```

Comment: If you read [`librosa.display.waveshow`](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.display.waveshow.html) documentation, you will find it only takes one positional argument and many keyword only arguments. I guess you want to write `librosa.display.waveplot(data, sr=sampling_rate)`.

Comment: If you read [`librosa.display.waveplot`](https://librosa.org/doc/0.8.1/generated/librosa.display.waveplot.html) documentation, you will find it is a deprecated function and does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error and resolved by adding "=" to.
So you should write like this as Jorge Luis said(Apr 19 at 14:58).

```
・librosa.display.waveplot(data, sr=10000) ##If sampling_rate is 10000. 
・librosa.display.waveplot(data, sr=sampling_rate) ##Of course, you can use valiable "sampling_rate".
```

Please try it.

[Conforence: Sample code on librosa HP](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.display.waveshow.html)

```
y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.ex('choice', hq=True), mono=False, duration=10)
librosa.display.waveshow(y, sr=sr, ax=ax[1]) # Here!!(sr=sr)
ax[1].set(title='Envelope view, stereo')
ax[1].label_outer()
```